# Passing the address of an object causes parent class constructor to be called

Tags: c++

main.cpp:

```
options my_options;
tree my_trees;
CODON_alphabet my_alphabet(1);
likelihood_engine my_likelihood(&my_options, &my_trees, &my_sites);
CODON_M0 m0(&my_trees, &my_alphabet, &my_likelihood);
```

The class CODON_alphabet has as a parent the class alphabet.  When I create the CODON_M0 object, for some reason the constructors for the classes alphabet and CODON_alphabet are each called twice.  This happens before the first line of the CODON_M0 constructor is hit.  Can anyone point me the right direction to figure out why this is happening?  If I'm missing any important information, please let me know.  Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry, I assumed everyone here could read my mind.  Here is some code that I've reduced to do as little as possible, but the unwanted constructors are still called.

```
class CODON_M0: public CODON_model
{
   public: 
   CODON_M0(tree* tree_ptr, CODON_alphabet* alpha_ptr, likelihood_engine* like_ptr)
}

class CODON_model: public model
{
    public:
    CODON_alphabet* my_alphabet;
    CODON_model(tree* tree_ptr, CODON_alphabet* alpha_ptr, likelihood_engine* like_ptr)
}

class model
{
   public:
   model() {}
}

class CODON_alphabet: public alphabet
{
    public:
    CODON_alphabet()
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n *** CODON_alphabet constructor called. *** \n\n\n";
    }
}

class alphabet
{
    public:
    alphabet()
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n *** alphabet constuctor called. *** \n\n\n";
    }
}
```

I'm stepping through the code in gdb and when I hit the line that creates the CODON_M0 object and step into the constructor, I see the messages that the alphabet and CODON_alphabet constructors have been called twice.  Why?

Comment: Without the code for `CODON_M0`, at the very least, we can only guess.  Ideally, please post a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

If `CODON_M0` has two data members of type `CODON_alphabet`, they will be initialized before the constructor enters and thus the constructors called.

Comment: Thanks Luchian.  I added more information above.  CODON_model has one data member of type CODON_alphabet*.